# Error al guardar imagen EF ASP.NET

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, entity-framework

Actualmente tengo en mi modelo la siguiente estructura para un campo imagen de mi bd

```
 [Table("especialidad")]
public class clsEspecialidad
{

    private int iId_Especialidad;

    [Key]
    [Column("id_especialidad")]
    [Display(Name = "Id Especialidad")]

    public int Id_Especialidad
    {
        get { return iId_Especialidad; }
        set { iId_Especialidad = value; }
    }


    private string iEspecialidad;

    [Column("especialidad")]
    [Required]
    [MinLength(6, ErrorMessage = "Campo Especialidad Min 6 Caracteres")]
    [MaxLength(120, ErrorMessage = "Campo Cargo Max 120 Caracteres")]
    [Display(Name = "Especialidad ")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string Especialidad
    {
        get { return iEspecialidad; }
        set { iEspecialidad = value; }
    }


    private string iDescripcion;

    [Column("descripcion")]
    [Required]
    [MinLength(6, ErrorMessage = "Campo Descripción Min 10 Caracteres")]
    [MaxLength(120, ErrorMessage = "Campo Descripción Max 200 Caracteres")]
    [Display(Name = "Descripción ")]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Descripcion
    {
        get { return iDescripcion; }
        set { iDescripcion = value; }
    }



    private byte[] iImagen;

    [Column("imagen")]
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Imagen ")]
    [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
    public byte[] Imagen
    {

        get {
            return iImagen;
        }
        set {
            iImagen = value;
        }
    }

    private bool iEstado;

    [Column("estado")]
    [Required]
    public bool Estado
    {
        get { return iEstado; }
        set { iEstado = value; }
    }

}
```

Al Ejecutar el sistema no muestra errores ,pero al intentar registrar una imagen a la bd me salta la Exception

> System.FormatException: La entrada no es una cadena Base 64 válida porque contiene un carácter que no es Base 64, más de dos caracteres de relleno o un carácter no válido entre los caracteres de relleno.

Mi Controlador

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id_Especialidad,Especialidad,Descripcion,Imagen,Estado")] clsEspecialidad clsEspecialidad)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.clsEspecialidades.Add(clsEspecialidad);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(clsEspecialidad);
    }
```

Y en mi vista tengo un input type file para mi imagen

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Especialidad", FormMethod.Post,
                                              new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })){ 

 @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>clsEspecialidad</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Especialidad, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Especialidad, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Especialidad, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Descripcion, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Descripcion, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Descripcion, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Imagen, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Imagen, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })*@
            @*@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Imagen, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })*@
            <input type="file" name="Imagen" value="" id="Imagen">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Estado, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="checkbox">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Estado)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Estado, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

}

Entiendo que es porqué me falta convertir a bytes la imagen obtenida ,¿ como puedo realizar esto y donde sería modelo ?  , controlador?.

Comment: coloca un breakpoint en "db.SaveChanges();", mira lo que tienes en la línea anterior: "db.clsEspecialidades.Add(clsEspecialidad);" selecciona lo que hay dentro de ese paréntesis, pantallazo y edita tu pregunta :D

Comment: Al parecer el ModelSate no es válido porque no ingresa al if .

Comment: agrega tu vista completa :D

Comment: @fredyfx editada.

Answer (score 0):

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id_Especialidad,Especialidad,Descripcion,Imagen,Estado")] clsEspecialidad clsEspecialidad, HttpPostedFileBase upload)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
      if (upload != null && upload.ContentLength > 0)
      {           
        using (var reader = new System.IO.BinaryReader(upload.InputStream))
        {
          var contenidoFoto = reader.ReadBytes(upload.ContentLength);
          clsEspecialidad.Imagen= contenidoFoto;
        }              
      }
        db.clsEspecialidades.Add(clsEspecialidad);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(clsEspecialidad);
}
```

Comment: ya listo hermano, respuesta actualizada :D

Comment: la variable upload es null?

Comment: debugueando llega al get del atributo y ahí retorna null y se va al dispose del controlador , sería mejor trabajr así o como lo plantean aquí que tampoco me resulta. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852102/convert-httppostedfilebase-to-byte

Comment: la variable "upload" es null?. Coloca un breakpoint antes del primer If y mira lo que hay en los parámetros que recibes en el ActionResult Create.

Comment: coloca tu modelo :D

Comment: mientras me hago un espacio para ver tu código, revisa este workshop que hice sobre ASP.net  MVC https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY :D

Comment: Trabajo con MYSQL , no eh tenido problemas hasta ahora con las imagenes.